# Add animation to replaceWith() jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to animate a replace with jquery action specifically the item which I am replacing the div with

```
jQuery('#banner-sign-up-container').replaceWith('<div id="credit-limit-receipt" class="receipt"></div>').animate({'margin-top': '50px'}, 4000);
```

I want the #credit-limit-receipt to slide upwards as shown in this fiddle but my code won't work. How do I do this?

I just want my text to roll up from the bottom like a receipt like in this jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/MvQsT/1/

Comment: I don't understand why would you do that. What is the use case?

Comment: To emulate a receipt printing off a machine

Answer (score 1):

You are using `replaceWith()` which will replace `banner-sign-up-container` to `credit-limit-receipt`, So DOM value is changed, but jquery chain is still trying to find `#banner-sign-up-container`, but that is not available so animate will not work.

You need to brake this code in two line.

Check below example:

```js
$(function(){
    $('#banner-sign-up-container').replaceWith('<div id="credit-limit-receipt" class="receipt">Hi there!</div>');
    $('#credit-limit-receipt').animate({'margin-top': '50px'}, 1000);
});
```

```css
div {
    background-color:#2795ee;
    width: 640px;
    margin:auto;
    margin-top: 300px;
    font-size:16px;
    text-align:center;
    padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="banner-sign-up-container">Something</div>
```

Comment: True. Was about to mention the same :) 

@Scott, you are trying to animate a div with it's ID, which is actually replace by new div and ID.